# How to convert html textarea value to json?

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

**Client**

```
.. some form
<textarea name="data"></textarea>
```

I will type to textarea like below

```
{title: 'Hello one!', author: 'someone'}
{title: 'Hello two!', author: 'mygf'}
{title: 'Hello three!', author: 'darthvader'}
```

And finally submit the form,

**Server**

Server will get above like

```
'{title: \'Hello one!\', author: \'someone\'}\r\n
{title: \'Hello two!\', author: \'mygf\'}\r\n
{title: \'Hello three!\', author: \'darthvader\'}\r\n'
```

At this point how can I convert it?

I tried:

```
 var dataArray = req.body.data.split('\r\n');
 for (var i=0; i< dataArray.length; i++){
     console.log(dataArray[i].title)  // err because dataArray[i] is not obj
 }
```

How can I make objectdarray correctly?

Comment: It would help if you just typed JSON in the first place. As it stands, you would have to write a parser for your custom data format.

Comment: why wouldn't you put proper valid json in textarea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is not valid JSON. If you use [valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) (keys and string values wrapped in double-quotes), then you can simply use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var data = '{"title": "Hello one!", "author": "someone"}\r\n{"title": "Hello two!", "author": "mygf"}\r\n{"title": "Hello three!", "author": "darthvader"}';
var dataArray = data.split('\r\n');

for (var i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++){
  dataArray[i] = JSON.parse(dataArray[i]);
  console.log(dataArray[i]);
}
```

If you want to allow invalid JSON, you'll need to analyze the strings and figure out where the keys & values are and add them to a newly created object.

Answer (score -2):

first, its not JSON. it just some of data array in javascript. why? because JSON using quotation mark in every key and value like

```
{"key":"value"}
```

second, for helping with less coding. you can add hidden input and set it value like as textarea value. Look at this code :

```
<textarea id="txta" name="txta">
<input type="hidden" name="txtahid" id="txtahid" value="">
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("txtahid").value = document.getElementById("txta").value
    },200);
</script>
```

Hopes it helps you.

Answer (score -3):

```
<textarea id = "textData" name="data"></textarea>

let textdata = $('#textData').value;
```

while sending text from client side 
you can use

```
let res = JSON.stringify(textdata);
```

and while fetching data

```
var dataArray = JSON.parse(req.body.data);
```

so the textArea data remains same.